# Is there any way to get the subpages with the largest number of views using Google Analytics's API?

Tags: google-analytics-api, pageviews

I'd like to see the pages with the largest number of post views that start with the "posts" slug: http://www.example.com/my-page/ should be ignored when counting, but http://www.example.com/posts/my-page/ should be included.

I'm not sure how to query the api to achieve this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a filter to the api query:

```
filters=ga:pagePath=~(/posts/)
```

You can test it out using the [Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) using the following values in these fields:

dimensions: `ga:pagePath`

metrics: `ga:pageviews`

filters: `ga:pagePath=~(/posts/)`

See also [filter operators in the filters section](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filters) for more information and to note that the forward slash `/` is not a reserved character so it can be used in your filter for matching. The backslash `\` is reserved.